# Adding headers to request/response of keycloak token endpoint

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-connect

Can we add custom headers to the token endpoint?

`curl --location --request POST 'https://localhost:8081/auth/realms/global/protocol/openid-connect/token' \

--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \

--data-urlencode 'client_id=login' \

--data-urlencode 'username=balabla@bla.com' \

--data-urlencode 'password=balbabsfeds@123' `

We are using userfederation with custom logic to determine whether the credentials are authentic. We’ve implemented the authentication spi shown below.
implements UserStorageProvider,
UserLookupProvider,
CredentialInputValidator,
CredentialInputUpdater,
UserRegistrationProvider

Answer (score 0):

You can extend Authenticator interface and read the custom header with

@Override
public void authenticate(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {

```
    List<String> customHeader = context.getSession().getContext().getRequestHeaders().getRequestHeader(customheader);
```

//perform action for accept and deny

}

place the custom jar under standalone folder (<=17 version) / place under /keycloak/providers/ directory above 18 version